# Order by field and its value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

How can I order by a field and its value? For example, say I have 10 records, of which:

- 2 records are active (`status` is `active`) and `favorite` is `true`
- 2 records are active (`status` is `active`) and `favorite` is `false`
- 3 records are completed (`status` is `completed`) and `favorite` is `true`
- 3 records are completed (`status` is `completed`) and `favorite` is `false`

How can I put the records in order as above? That is,

- active and favorite - true
- active and favorite - false
- completed and favorite - true
- completed and favorite - false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose your model name is Restaurant.

If you are using ActiveRecord with rails, you may try this,

```
Restaurant.order('status, favorite DESC')
```

Comment: thanks but I done by Restaurant.order(status: :asc, favorite: :desc), but thanks your answer also work.